# tag $ref don't show content openapi3.0

Tags: swagger, openapi, api-doc

I have this piece of the spec to api, with about content in an external file:

```
paths:
  /about:
    $ref: ./api/about.yml#/about
```

In this way, `about` content doesn't load when I make a bundle using [openapi-cli-tool](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-cli-tool/). But, if I increase one auxiliar tag, the content is loaded.

```
paths:
  /about:
    whatever:
      $ref: ./api/about.yml#/about
```

Using the `whatever` tag, the Swagger Editor show a Structural error, but without her don't load. Some tips?

Obs: I already saw some errors in the `$ref` tag in the openapi 3.0.

Comment: What's the content of `about.yml`?

Comment: ```about:
  get:
    tags:
    - about
    summary: get_about
    operationId: get_about
    parameters:
    - name: Authorization
      in: header
      description: '''Authorization'' header with value ''Bearer <access_token>'''
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        default: Bearer <access_token>    
    responses:      
      403:
        description: Customer unauthorized
        content: {}
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT```